# Excel - allow saving as pdf but no saving of original document

Tags: excel, pdf

I have a heavily formulated workbook which will be used by staff members who will paste in potentially confidential client information. The workbook then comes up with graphics and data to summarize the imputed information

In an ideal world, the people using the program will be able to Save specific sheets as a PDF and would be able to close the program without saving changes to the worksheet but Excel always demands to save the template first, THEN will allow PDFs. This is obviously a problem as if a person uses it, paste's in a client's information and saves the result as a PDF then whoever next opens the Excel workbook will have that previous client's information showing.

SO. I either need a way to tell Excel to not require compulsory saving to allow PDF conversion or another option which will result in the same thing.

I should also note that the workbook has to allow users to paste in information so I don't imagine a Read Only will help :/

I have also attempted using a Macro-Enabled Template which still has the same problem

I imagine there's a ridiculously simple solution to this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Making the file Read only does _not_ prevent the user from entering data, it just prevents them from _saving the file_ - sounds like just what you want

Comment: Thanks for the response but Excel still insists that there be a copy saved in order to produce the PDF. It's not really the end of the world because at least this way the file is only saved in the staff member's personal files but it's not really ideal

Comment: For me, Save As|pdf does _not_ require the wb to be saved normally first